# How geometry, and hence, a tight-binding Hamiltonian dictates the eigenvalues?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, tight-binding

Considering an 'N' atom system, how should we understand the geometric dependence on the calculated eigenvalue spectrum by solving the nearest neighbor tight-binding Hamiltonian?

A simple example being the difference in the eigenvalue spectrum for [anthracene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthracene) and [phenanthrene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenanthrene) (where just one of the benzene ring position is changed). For anthracene HOMO-LUMO gap (HLG) value is 1.988 eV and for phenanthrene it is 2.905 eV, i.e. ~1 eV difference (where I considered the hopping parameter, t = 2.8).

Here are the HOMO, LUMO, HLG values:

-0.9941   0.9941   1.988    anthracene

-1.4525   1.4525   2.905    phenanthrene

Through Molecular Orbital theory, one can understand this (to an extent) by joining MOs of napthalene and butadiene (as we do in LCAO approach) in different ways to get resultant MOs which are ordered in energies according to their overlap. This give HOMO of phenanthrene being more stable than anthracene. But this approach, seems not be so easy as we go to bigger systems.

To be specific, I am studying an example of carbon dots (or graphene quantum dots) consisting of 28 carbon atoms. With these 28 atoms, I was able to generate several geometries (I have considered only planar ones for my study). For these different geometries, I am finding different HOMO-LUMO gap (HLG) values (varied between ~ 0 to 1 eV). Importantly, I am finding the HLG changes in the order of 1 eV, just by moving a pair of carbon atoms from one edge to the other.

As my Hamiltonian just accounts for the hopping of an electron to the nearest neighbor site, I was wondering how to connect the geometry with the eigenvalue spectrum. I have already tried to understand it through Huckel's rule, Clar's sextets and Lieb's theorem, but, none of them is satisfactory (to me).